# How do I know which of my groups are significantly different? Kruskal-Wallis, Dunn's test

Tags: nonparametric, kruskal-wallis-test, dunn-test

Answers to other posts that are almost identical to my question are still confusing to me...

my data is nonparametric, unequal sample size, unequal variance, so I've decided that kruskal-wallis is best for comparing multiple populations, here are my results:

```
>kruskal.test(Area~Dehiscence2)

Kruskal-Wallis rank sum test
data:  Area by Dehiscence2
Kruskal-Wallis chi-squared = 15.601, df = 5, p-value = 0.008081
```

**Null rejected**, there is a difference between the populations.

[image: dunn's test to determine which populations are different]

The answer that shows up for this question is:

> the upper number for each comparison is Dunn's pairwise z test statistic. The lower number is in this example the raw p-value associated with the test (i.e. you would compare to α/2α/2, although this p-value changes depending on the family-wise error rate or false discovery rate multiple comparisons adjustment option.

What does it mean by "you would compare to α/2α/2"?, How do I know which of my groups are significantly different?

Comment: Hi there, I've viewed the tour and it doesn't say anything about self studies. What do you mean by self study? I just have a stats question--I don't understand how to interpret my data. Thanks!

Comment: Hi there, this is data that I've collected for my research. I could add the self-study tag, though I think the only part I am stuck on is how to tell which of the groups are different from each other from looking at my Dunn's test results.

Is it safe to say that the pvalues are all I need to interpret the results? right now my interpretation is that INB and DE are different, whereas there is no difference between IN and DE and IN and INB. 

I'm not sure why the other groups (DEA, INA, and blank) are all included on the test even though the tests in R say that they exclude empty values

Comment: If this is from your thesis, then you would not need the `[self-study]` tag.  As I understand the table, the blank area is the p-value for that factor, independent of the others.  The other values would be the interactions and their associate p-values.

Comment: Please, someone, I would still like a straight answer for this! I understand that the other values are the interactions and their associate p-values but do they tell me what I'm looking for? (i.e. INB and DE are different from each other whereas there is no difference between IN and DE and between IN and INB.

Comment: The unsolved mystery here is what the first column is doing (the one with no header). Does the help for whatever software you are using give a clue? The only issue which stops a clear answer to your question in your last comment is whether you want or need to make any sort of adjustment for multiple comparisons.

Comment: I think the reason that first column is there, is because my X variables are groups (DE, IN, INA, INB, DEA) and in some cases, there are missing values because those species weren't looked at. When I ran the tests (KW and Dunn's), R told me that the missing values would be excluded..but for some reason they still show up. (Even INA and DEA shouldn't be there because the sample size is too small, only 1 species found with those characteristics). So, I'd like to ignore those characteristics if I can. I also made a new datasheet and removed those variables. Do I just need the p-values for determi

Comment: ning where the difference is?